# serveIndex module change UI

Tags: node.js, directory, display

I am new to node.js

My aim is to just to change the look of the directory listing which gets displayed on serveIndex than the standard display which is rendered by the browser.

On running the below code the available files and directories under public directory get listed. I can  further click on the sub-directories and see the listing in them. However there is little control on the ui of the screen that gets displayed I would like to change it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'), serveIndex('public', {'icons': true}));
app.listen(8080);
```

How can i change the layout by altering the  html of directory listing alongwith my css and not the standard index file  which is called by serveIndex module.

I tried  using

```
app.use(express.static('public'), serveIndex('public', {
  'icons': true,
  'stylesheet': 'mycss.css'
}}));
```

1]I am not sure how will i apply css to the standard elements which get rendered because of serveIndex.

2]Also please let me know how can i alter the existing html that is generated and apply css to it.

Thanks